# HTTP Client - Best practices

Tags: c#, asynchronous, http, stream, xamarin

I've made a HTTP client and would like some tips to improve my code, it's supposed to be built for xamarin forms but should work with any implementation.

My goal of this project was to learn more about HTTP client and also create a project that I can just copy the class into any new project where I need web access, even other than mobile.

Link to repository
https://github.com/oscarjaergren/HttpClientBestPractices

```
/// <summary>
        ///     The request provider holds our Get/Put request to our APIs in generic format.
        ///     Implement this class in your services and use this to make requests to the API.
        /// </summary>
        public class RequestProvider : IRequestProvider
        {
            /// <summary> Json serialization rules </summary>
            private static JsonSerializerOptions serializerSettings;

            /// <summary> Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RequestProvider" /> class. </summary>
            public RequestProvider()
            {
                serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
            }

            /// <summary> Send a DELETE request to the specified Uri as an asynchronous operation.</summary>
            /// <param name="uri"> The uri we are sending our delete request. </param>
            /// <param name="cancellationToken"> Used to cancel the job </param>
            /// <param name="token"> The token used by the API to authorize and identify. </param>
            /// <returns> The <see cref="Task" />. </returns>
            public static async Task DeleteRequest(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken, string token = "")
            {
                HttpClient httpClient = CreateHttpClient(token);
                await httpClient.DeleteAsync(uri, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            /// <summary> Gets data from API in stream form authenticated users </summary>
            /// <param name="uri"> The uri we are sending our get request to. </param>
            /// <param name="cancellationToken"> Used to cancel the job </param>
            /// <param name="token"> The token identifying who we are. </param>
            /// <typeparam name="TResult"> Gets the generic results returned back </typeparam>
            /// <returns> The result of the task is returned <see cref="Task" />.</returns>
            public static async Task<TResult> GetAsyncStream<TResult>(
                Uri uri,
                CancellationToken cancellationToken,
                string token = "")
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response;
                using (HttpRequestMessage request = CreateRequest(uri))
                {
                    using (HttpClient httpClient = CreateHttpClient(token))
                    {
                        response = await httpClient.SendAsync(
                                       request,
                                       HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead,
                                       cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                }

                await HandleResponse(response).ConfigureAwait(false);

                // Prints the data for us in debug mode
    #if DEBUG
                using (Stream contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(contentStream))
                {
                    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Debug.WriteLine("RECEIVED: " + text);
                    return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<TResult>(
                               contentStream,
                               serializerSettings,
                               cancellationToken);
                }

    #else
                using (Stream contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<TResult>(
                               contentStream,
                               serializerSettings,
                               cancellationToken);
                }
    #endif
            }

            /// <summary> Enables us to connect to sites with localhost as certificate, enables GZIP decompression </summary>
            /// <returns> The <see cref="HttpClientHandler" />. </returns>
            public static HttpClientHandler GetHttpHandler()
            {
                var handler = new HttpClientHandler
                                  {
                                      AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip,
                                      ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>
                                          {
                                              if (cert.Issuer.Equals("CN=localhost", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                                              {
                                                  return true;
                                              }

                                              return errors == SslPolicyErrors.None;
                                          }
                                  };
                return handler;
            }

            /// <summary> Returns the static method </summary>
            public Task DeleteAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken, string token = "")
            {
                return DeleteRequest(uri, cancellationToken, token);
            }

            /// <summary> Returns the static method </summary>
            public Task<TResult> GetAsync<TResult>(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken, string token = "")
            {
                return GetAsyncStream<TResult>(uri, cancellationToken, token);
            }

            /// <summary> The post async posts data to an API when logged in </summary>
            /// <param name="uri"> The uri we are posting to. </param>
            /// <param name="data"> The data we are posting. </param>
            /// <param name="cancellationToken"> Used to cancel the job </param>
            /// <param name="token"> The token identifying who we are. </param>
            /// <param name="header"> The header type we are using to post with HTTP client. </param>
            /// <typeparam name="TResult"> returns the generic results </typeparam>
            /// <returns> The result of the task is returned. <see cref="Task" />. </returns>
            public Task<TResult> PostAsync<TResult>(
                Uri uri,
                TResult data,
                CancellationToken cancellationToken,
                string token = "",
                string header = "")
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            /// <summary> Send POST request to API from unauthenticated user </summary>
            /// <param name="uri"> The uri we are posting to. </param>
            /// <param name="data"> The data we are posting. </param>
            /// <param name="clientId"> The client id (who we are, i.e mobile). </param>
            /// <param name="clientSecret"> The client secret. (encryption) </param>
            /// <param name="cancellationToken"> Used to cancel the job </param>
            /// <typeparam name="TResult"> The result if it is success or failure </typeparam>
            /// <returns> The task is returned <see cref="Task" />. </returns>
            public async Task<TResult> PostAsync<TResult>(
                Uri uri,
                string data,
                string clientId,
                string clientSecret,
                CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response;
                using (HttpClient httpClient = CreateHttpClient(string.Empty))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientId) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientSecret))
                    {
                        AddBasicAuthenticationHeader(httpClient, clientId, clientSecret);
                    }

                    var content = new StringContent(data);
                    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    content.Dispose();
                }

                await HandleResponse(response).ConfigureAwait(false);
                string serialized = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                var result = await Task.Run(() => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TResult>(serialized, serializerSettings), cancellationToken)
                                 .ConfigureAwait(false);

                return result;
            }

            /// <summary> The create http client. </summary>
            /// <param name="token"> The token default value is empty. </param>
            /// <returns> The <see cref="HttpClient" /> </returns>
            private static HttpClient CreateHttpClient(string token = "")
            {
                HttpClientHandler handler = GetHttpHandler();
                var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                {
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
                }

                return httpClient;
            }

            private static HttpRequestMessage CreateRequest(Uri uri)
            {
                return new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
            }

            /// <summary>
            ///     Handles the response via HTTP via checking if the Https call was valid.
            ///     If not throws exception.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="response"> The response. </param>
            /// <returns> The <see cref="Task" />. </returns>
            /// <exception cref="ServiceAuthenticationException"> Throws a service authentication error if not here. </exception>
            /// <exception cref="HttpRequestException"> Throws a general HttpRequestException unless forbidden or unauthorized. </exception>
            private static async Task HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
            {
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                    throw new ServiceAuthenticationException(response.StatusCode, content);
                }
            }

            /// <summary> The add basic authentication header. </summary>
            /// <param name="httpClient"> The http client. </param>
            /// <param name="clientId"> The client id. </param>
            /// <param name="clientSecret"> The client secret.</param>
            private void AddBasicAuthenticationHeader(HttpClient httpClient, string clientId, string clientSecret)
            {
                if (httpClient == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientId) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientSecret))
                {
                    return;
                }

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new BasicAuthenticationHeaderValue(clientId, clientSecret);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Required reading: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/ and https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/

Comment: Hey Jesse, thanks for responding. I've already read both of those, great links and part of what inspired me to try to do this. 

Although the posts can be a bit conflicting at times. 
https://johnthiriet.com/efficient-api-calls/

I've tried to take the best of these three and a few forum posts

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sold on what I read at John Thiriet's page there - the `using (var client = new HttpClient())` has been considered a **bad** practice for years.